# Is the shadow between the status bar and toolbar desired for material design apps?

Tags: android, material-design, android-support-library, android-support-design

I noticed the Google templates on Android Studio have a little of a shadow between the status bar and the toolbar. My graphic designer thinks I should not have that but I just don't know since the templates have it.

What is the correct way of doing it?

Here are two screenshots of apps created with the Android Studio templates and zero code modifications.

[image]
[image]

EDIT: just to clarify, I know this is happening because of `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>` which is actually desired because on my app I have a nav drawer. But my question isn't as much how to fix it, I am wondering if this is the way Google wants it to work?

Also I should mention I'm only testing on lollipop and marshmallow.

Answer (score 1):

No, it shouldn't be there. Status bar should be flat without any shadows. Just take a look at this page: https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/color.html#color-color-schemes

[image]

This is my transparent status bar with a drawer running on Marshmallow. The shadow is not there.

[image]

Theme:

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
```

I'm drawing colored insets using a modified ScrimInsetsFrameLayout - https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.java

---

Edit

To be exact, this layout is constructed from the following xml:

```
<carbon.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <carbon.widget.LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:carbon_insetColor="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <carbon.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/drawerMenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="?attr/carbon_colorBackground"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:carbon_elevation="@dimen/carbon_elevationDrawer"
        app:carbon_insetTop="0dp"/>

</carbon.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It can be found here along with full sources: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ZieIony/Carbon/master/samples/src/main/res/layout/activity_navigationview.xml

The layout with insets pushes its content down and draws colored rectangle over inset space. That's for the content layout. The drawer menu has similiar layout as its root, but its insets are set to 0dp so the menu can take all screen space. The *fitsSystemWindows* flag is the key.

Comment: So you are using that as the first view on your main activity layout?

Comment: I looked at the io schedule app code and I don't see where they use that frame layout, it also says it is deprecated. I added it to a new project made straight from the templates and it pushes the toolbar under the status bar.

Comment: As I said it's a modified version. ScrimInsetsFrameLayout is not perfect, but it was a good start for me. It was used in the previous version of Google app. I've added more details to the answer. I didn't want to add Carbon to the answer, because it's too large to be useful as a sample.